# Semantic UI React Menu pointing won't change active state on Route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux, semantic-ui-react

I've build small SPA in React using Semantic UI React. Menu is working as it should and when I click on any of the menu items, it takes me where its supposed to.

The problem is that, if I go to a page/Route and from there change my page/Route to another one, active field in pointing Menu stays pointing at the previous page.

Everything is imported the way it should. I just want to find the way for my menu to always point at the appropriate Route that is currently shown.

Here is my code:

```
render() {

const { activeItem } = this.state

return (
  <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Menu pointing>
            <Menu.Item name='Home' as={Link} to='/home' active={activeItem === 'Home'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Item name='Regions' as={Link} to='/regions' active={activeItem === 'Regions'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Item name='Countries' as={Link} to='/countries' active={activeItem === 'Countries'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Item name='AllCountries' as={Link} to='/allcountries' active={activeItem === 'AllCountries'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
            <Menu.Menu position='left'>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Form.Group onSubmit={this.submit}>
                  <Input placeholder='Search...' value={this.state.searchTerm} onChange={this.takeTerm} onKeyPress={this.showData}/>
                  <Link to="/countrydata"><Button type="submit" circular icon="search" /></Link>
                </Form.Group>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Menu>
            <Button.Group>
              <Button>English</Button>
              <Button.Or text="or"/>
              <Button>Francais</Button>
              <Button.Or text="or"/>
              <Button>Italiano</Button>
            </Button.Group>
          </Menu>
          <Segment>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/regions" component={Regions}/>
            <Route path="/countries" component={Countries}/>
            <Route path="/allcountries" component={AllCountries}/>
            <Route path="/countrydata" component={Country} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
          </Segment>
          {this.state.notFound ? (<div className="showError">Searched country does not exist</div>) : <div></div>}
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
)
```

}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem today or, at least, a similar one. So I resolved my problem by replacing Link with NavLink and by removing Semantic's "handleItemClick". We don't need Semantic to handle active Menu.Item since react-router can do this with NavLink.

```
<Menu.Item name='Countries' as={NavLink} to='/countries' />
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem could you please point to me what `NavLink` would look like?

Answer (score 0):

We use a component:

```
const MenuLink = ({ to, exact, ...rest }) => (
  <Route path={to} exact={exact} children={({ match }) => (
    <Link to={to}><Menu.Item active={!!match}{...rest} /></Link>
  )} />
);
```